# Hide/Remove first newline/blank-line of html code-section using <pre><code> tag

Tags: html, css, newline, pre, blank-line

I'm working on a website that has some code and I would like to write:

```
<pre><code>
line 1
line 2
</code></pre>
```

But that produces an empty line at the beginning like this as output

```
[A Blank line in here that I don't want]    
line 1
line 2
```

I know if I write like this there will be no blank lines but I like to write as shown above.

```
<pre><code>line 1
line 2
</code></pre>
```

Please suggest me what can I do, with CSS if possible, to hide or remove the first newline/blank-line so that I can keep the newline in my code without blank-lines appearing at the beginning of all my code sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I see it doable is:

#### Using just a bit of JavaScript:

```js
const code = document.querySelectorAll("pre code");
[...code].forEach(el => el.textContent = el.textContent.replace(/^\n/,''));
```

```css
pre {border: 1px solid #ddd;}
```

```html
<pre><code>
1 line
2 line

4 line
</code></pre>

<pre><code>1 line
2 line

4 line
</code></pre>

<pre><code>

2 line. (Keep intentional newline above)

4 line
</code></pre>
```

#### CSS

Another, just really **bad** way is to use only CSS `pre:first-line { font-size:0; }` -- but that's really bad since it forces you to always leave the very-first line empty (otherwise such text will not appear on screen due to `font-size: 0`)

#### `white-space` fail

Any other way like playing with `white-space` combinations on the `<pre>` and `<code>` tags will not get anything as desired.

Comment: Your CSS fix doesn't work for me but the JS solution does. I'm kind of loathe to use JS to fix a static issue like this but it seems to be the only way.

Answer (score 1):

> This is how the code related tags behave. The **code** tag is inline.

```
<code>
    var Name = "My Name";
    alert(Name);
</code>
```

*Output:*

```
var Name = "My Name"; alert(Name);
```

> The **pre** tag does not show the first empty line.

```
<pre>
    var Name = "My Name";
    alert(Name);
</pre>
```

*Output:*

```
    var Name = "My Name";
    alert(Name);
```

> The **pre** tag along with **code** tag always shows the first line

```
<pre><code>
    var Name = "My Name";
    alert(Name);
</code></pre>
```

*Output:*

```
[A blank line appears here]    
    var Name = "My Name";
    alert(Name);
```

> Smart way of getting the blank line out of your way is to fill the first line with a default or useful comment. then you start writing your code from the next line. :

```
<pre><code>// Javascript Code
    var Name = "My Name";
    alert(Name);
</code></pre>
```

*Output:*

```
// Javascript Code
    var Name = "My Name";
    alert(Name);
```

> Or

```
<pre><code>// Javascript to display your name
    var Name = "My Name";
    alert(Name);
</code></pre>
```

*Output:*

```
// Javascript to display your name
    var Name = "My Name";
    alert(Name);
```

Comment: I'm not getting your *`"Smart way of getting rid of first empty line that works in all browser:"`* - what's *smart* in there other than adding `// Javascript Code` nuisance?

Comment: You fill the first line with a default or useful comment. then you start writing your code from the next line.

Comment: **This does not answers the question.** You say ***getting rid of the first empty line*** which is not true at all. 1) you're **not** getting rid of it 2) you're **adding** extra code comments in the first line.

Comment: Thanks for your __nice__ catch, I rephrased myself for those who __may not__ understand what I am saying even after seeing the output just  below.

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty much not useful for me. I have upwards of fifty code blocks on a single page, I'm not doing this for each one.